# Any reason to put implements interface to class?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to type script, just browsing their tutorial and trying some coding in their playground but found something strange.

For example this code:

```
class foobar implements Ifoobar
{
    full: string;
    constructor (public foo, public bar)
    {
        this.full = foo + bar;
    }
}

interface Ifoobar
{
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

function test(ifoobar: Ifoobar)
{
    return ifoobar.foo + ifoobar.bar;
}

var obj = new foobar("hello", "world");


document.body.innerHTML = test(obj);
```

works if you put

```
class foobar implements Ifoobar
```

or just

```
class foobar
```

so what's the point of using interface if contract itself was not enforced?

**UPDATE**
My main concern is actually on this line:

```
document.body.innerHTML = test(obj);
```

this should throw error right since foobar doesn't use implements Ifoobar, and test(ifoobar: Ifoobar) as specified in method argument should accept only Ifoobar. To me it feels like typescript just plainly think that foobar is implements Ifoobar even though it isn't.

Comment: How are you evaluating the script? What process are you using to build/verify it first?

Comment: @Dai I haven't build/verify it first, still in http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground and trying out things or two.

Comment: This is the main use for `implements Ifoobar`: http://bit.ly/1FHmopN - it helps you to ensure Ifoobar has the correct structure (and also supplies information to other developers about the usage of the `foobar` class, thus ensuring it remains compatible with the interface over time).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't work.  First, the `public` keyword is a syntax error.  Second, it will refuse to compile since `foobar` does not implement `Ifoobar`. Third, you're correct that `test(obj)` should also be a type error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript uses [duck typing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces), which means if the members match, types are considered compatible. That's why the code is still valid after removing `implements Ifoobar` - a `foobar` can be treated as a `Ifoobar` since it has all the members declared by `Ifoobar`.

And TypeScript does enforce the contract. If you remove/rename either member `foo` or `bar`, the compiler will generate errors.

Answer (score 1):

> what's the point of using interface if contract itself was not enforced

Its enforced at compile time e.g. the following fails to compile (because I removed `public` from `bar`):

```
class foobar implements Ifoobar // ERROR property `bar` is missing in foobar 
{
    full: string;
    constructor (public foo, bar)
    {
        this.full = foo + bar;
    }
}

interface Ifoobar
{
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}
```

It is really for the class *author* (not consumer) to ensure that they follow the contract (`interface`).

## More

Please note that types are structuring in typescript and compile failure does not mean that js will not be generated. See [why typescript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html)